# Missing firmware wifi iwlwifi-7265d-25.ucode and iwlwifi-7265d-26.ucode

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, firmware, iwlwifi

I just installed kali linux in my dell inspiron 5240, while installation it says missing firmware and it surely of wifi networks. I then chose not to load it from my media as most probably they must not be there in the installation media.

So is there a solution to load these firmware after installation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package:

```
apt install firmware-iwlwifi 
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

You should have `non-free` in your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

[Debian: iwlwifi](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi)